# How to use python gettext with PO files from http://translationproject.org?

Tags: python, django, gettext

I'm new to Python and Django. I want to start a Django multi langual project. I see that I should use gettext to translate the strings but I'm not getting how it works.

For example. My main language is Portuguese, and I need to translate to English and Chinese. What PO files I need, and how to get the files?

Sorry if the question is confusing.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

["Overview of GNU gettext"](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#Overview)

I recommend taking some time to read over the document that article is part of, the Python documentation for the `gettext` module, and the Django i18n and l10n documentation.